# How to differentiate between existing newlines and \n in variable?

Tags: javascript, string, newline

I have a text like this:

```
123\n456
789
```

How can I save this text in a variable without loosing the information if the newline was made with `\n` or with a existing newline?
If I save it with template strings like this:

```
var str = `123\n456
789`;
```

the saved variable will be `123\n456\n789`. Is there a way to differentiate between the two?

Comment: No, there is not. It's the same string. Just different ways to format the code. If you *want* different strings (to actually represent the text), you must escape your backslashes, even in a template string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I save this text in a variable, as a string containing the `\n` sequence not a linebreak?

You need to either escape the backslash in the string literal:

```
var str = `123\\n456
789`; //      ^^
```

or you can use a template literal tagged with [`String.raw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw):

```
var str = String.raw`123\n456
789`; //  ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what your looking for?

```
var str = `123\\n456
789`;
console.log(str);
```